# @Embeddable or @Entity which one should we choose

Tags: spring, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

Let's say I have an entity `Offer`, that has many prices.

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "offer")
data class Offer(
   val prices: List<Price>,
   @Id
   val id: Long? = null
)
```

Does it make sense to make `Price` an `Entity` or it's better to mark it as `Embeddable`? What in case there will be an offer with the same price? Perhaps we could reuse the price, or shouldn't we?

I'm looking for a good explanation of when we should use `Entity` and when `Embeddable`. Perhaps we could use it as an `Entity` but set the `orphanRemoval = true`, so the child in this case `Price` will be always removed together with an `Offer`.

Comment: Does the `Price` have an *identity*, in a way that is referenceable from other entities? E.g. is a "Price" object something set by the product design team, that applies possibly to many products? If another product has the same price, should it point (refer) to the same instance? If the value of a "Price" changes, should this change affect all products with the same price? If so, it makes sense for the `Price` to be an entity.

Comment: No it shouldn't. Products are independent from each other, but I thought that it would make sense to use a price that already exists in case it's the same I.e. thousand dollar or whatever.

Comment: Embeddable is just a way to write reusable entity code. For example in my app I have columns for user rights in various tables, this is an embeddable since the columns are the same in all these entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't definitely try to reuse prices between `Offer`s. The reason is that you might change that price for whatever reason and it will inadvertently change for all `Offer`s. To me this is just asking for troubles and bugs to appear. Unless there is a very good reason in terms of your business case that really makes it mandatory for doing so, I wouldn't do it.

Having written this, with the information that you gave I would definitely go with `@Embeddable` because it does seem to be. very beneficial to have a separate entity and table for the `Price`.

Comment: I understand, so in case I know that I won't need to Query the `Price` then I should use `@Embeddable` but let say there is a class that also shouldn't impact the other `Offer`s, but there is a need to Query for this class via `JpaRepository` then it make sense to make it an `@Entity`?

Comment: Generally speaking, I would say yes if it makes sense to get the objects of that other class on their own and not "attached" with the `Offer`.